# change the position of data on pie chart

Tags: r, pie-chart

Using the following code, I get the pie chart. "Mon" starts from the middle of the pie chart. I would like to get "Mon" on the top of the pie chart. Are there any way to start "Mon" from the top (Thu's place) and Tue (wed's Place) etc.

```
B <- c(2, 4, 5, 7, 12, 14, 16)
pie(B, main="My Piechart", col=rainbow(length(B)),
labels=c("Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat","Sun"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the pie chart to be clockwise.

```
pie(B, main="My Piechart", col=rainbow(length(B)),
   labels=c("Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat","Sun"), clockwise = T)
```

[image]